# MYSQL - Retrieve the max Count kill from a group by (1 row per victim)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve a list of 'nemesis' from my tables.

**Table Player  :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats_players (
    idPlayerSteam BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255))
```

**Table Event :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats_events (
    idEvent INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idPlayerSteam BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    dateOccurs DATETIME,
    idPlayerSteamVictim BIGINT UNSIGNED)
```

The Data :

```
INSERT INTO stats_players (idPlayerSteam, name) VALUES
(1,'bob'), (2,'tom'),(3,'robby'),(4,'dany'),(5,'john');

INSERT INTO stats_events (idPlayerSteam,type,dateOccurs,idPlayerSteamVictim) VALUES
(1,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:12:12',3),
(1,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:15:12',3),
(1,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:16:12',3),
(1,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:17:12',3),
(2,'PVP','2016-05-05 13:12:12',3),
(2,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:19:12',3),
(2,'PVP','2016-05-05 12:20:12',3),
(3,'PVP','2016-05-06 12:12:12',2),
(3,'PVP','2016-05-06 12:12:12',1),
(4,'PVP','2016-05-06 12:12:12',5),
(4,'PVP','2016-05-06 12:12:12',5),
(4,'PVP','2016-05-06 12:12:12',5);
```

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d0E7.png)

**What I want to retrieve :**

- The 'nemesis' of one other player
- the 'nemesis' of each player, by which I mean the opponent with highest number of kills recorded against that player

[what I want and what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sigst.png)

**The closest request I can get :**

```
SELECT v.idPlayerSteam,v.name as victim,k.idPlayerSteam,k.name as killer, count(*)
    FROM stats_players v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_events e ON v.idPlayerSteam = e.idPlayerSteamVictim
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_players k ON e.idPlayerSteam = k.idPlayerSteam
    WHERE e.type='PVP'  
    GROUP BY v.idPlayerSteam,k.idPlayerSteam
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
    ORDER BY v.idPlayerSteam, COUNT(*) DESC
```

It almost works but I can get just ONE ROW per victim (the first one in Kill count)

I know I can use sub request but I can't figure how.. :(

Comment: post your current output and desired one

Comment: You're halfway there but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, I think your question should read *"the 'nemesis' of each player, by which I mean the opponent with highest number of kills recorded against that player"*

Comment: thanks, I update my request.

Comment: I've added some screenshots

Comment: On your screen what you want is on the right or the left ?

Comment: What I want is on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a query which I think does what you want.

It's an ugly one and probably not optimized but it seems to be working.
It additionally displays the killer's ID and how many times did the nemesis killed the victim.

```
SELECT sp.*, (
  SELECT idPlayerSteam FROM stats_events se WHERE se.idPlayerSteamVictim = sp.idPlayerSteam
  GROUP BY idPlayerSteamVictim ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, dateOccurs DESC LIMIT 1
) 'nemesis_id',
(
  SELECT (SELECT name FROM stats_players spx WHERE spx.idPlayerSteam = se.idPlayerSteam) FROM stats_events se WHERE se.idPlayerSteamVictim = sp.idPlayerSteam
  GROUP BY idPlayerSteamVictim ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, dateOccurs DESC LIMIT 1
) 'nemesis_name',(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats_events se WHERE se.idPlayerSteamVictim = sp.idPlayerSteam AND idPlayerSteam = nemesis_id
  GROUP BY idPlayerSteamVictim ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, dateOccurs DESC LIMIT 1
) 'kills' FROM stats_players sp
```

When someone is an "ex-aequo nemesis" the latest kill takes priority.
It uses a groupped sub-query - which seems to work in the MySQL 5.7
Here's a link to a "fiddle" I've used to test it:
http://rextester.com/JRK5385

Comment: I'm glad it does ;)
The best way to say thank you would be an up-vote and/or accepted answer ;>

Comment: Done !I didn't notice the "accepted" :D But I still can't upvote :/